# unable to move form input field to center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a small ToDo App. I am trying to place `input` field and submit button in the centre, but alignment going to left side.

```css
#todo {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#todo .form-group {
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#id-button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<div id="todo">
  <p>
    <h3>Add New ToDo</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add New ToDo Item">
        <button id="id-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/graaj/j3augyfb/9/)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your example has them in the center, or ? what do you mean

Comment: @ajobi, Check my JSFiddle link in the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

> When you looking for centering the contents, then CSS has a beautiful class called `flex` and one of the property called `justify-content:center;` which will take care of the alignment.

More on [Justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)

add this:

```
#todo .form-group {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;     
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
#todo {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#todo .form-group {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

#id-button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="todo">
  <p>
    <h3>
      Add New ToDo
    </h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add New ToDo Item">
        <button id="id-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either modify the css of the .form-group to the below as correctly pointed by below user. Justify-content is the proper way to solve it.

```
#todo .form-group {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But since you're using bootstrap as a css framework. You could also add `<div class="col-xs-4"></div>` in the start of `<div class="form-group">` as the first child. Refer Bootstrap docs for grid structure. [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

```
form {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    width: 50%;
}     

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<div id="todo">
  <p>
    <h3>Add New ToDo</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
       <form>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add New ToDo Item">
        <button id="id-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few notices on your code:

- your `<p>` tag has no closing.
- try removing the "form-group" `<div>` and `class="col-xs-4"`.
- resize the input and out a `<br>` tag.
  your code would be as you desired.

the `col-xs-4` and (I think) `form-group` are Bootstrap classes that override whatever you are trying to do. So, either wrap your code in different `<div>` or override it in your CSS. Also if you want to use the col class you have to wrap that div in another `<div>` with `"row"` class.